# How to control the strength and intensity of IES lights?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, light

I have added an IES light to my blender project and I want to decrease the strength of the light. In the image below you can see that my light is much too powerful. How can I adjust the strength of the light?.[image]

[image: light in cycles]
[image: cycles material for the light]

Comment: Perhaps the strength slider in the middle of your node screenshot? (You will probably want to remove the driver first.)

Comment: @pycoder sorry i did not get what you mean. I have just imported the ies that i have download. Can you please go in details how can i adjust. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the *IES* lamp in the *3D Viewport* and press <kbd>N</kbd> to get the properties panel and scroll right to the bottom where it says *Lamp Properties* and there you will see a strength and color regulator.